# How to find Vertical Plane ARFoundation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to place a placement Indicator on the plane, and place an object at the position of the indicator when the user taps, but the indicator disappears on vertical planes.

I tried using default planes, and it does detect the vertical planes

Here is my code

```
    void Start()
    {
        arOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlacementPose();
        UpdatePlacementIndicator();

        if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            PlaceObject();
        }
    }

    private void PlaceObject()
    {
        Instantiate(objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementIndicator()
    {
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
            placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementPose()
    {
        var screenCenter = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
        var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
        arOrigin.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.Planes);

        placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementPose = hits[0].pose;

            var cameraForward = Camera.current.transform.forward;
            var cameraBearing = new Vector3(cameraForward.x, 0, cameraForward.z).normalized;
            placementPose.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraBearing);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect all the planes
Go to Detection mode and select Everything
If you want to detect only the horizontal planes
Go to Detection mode and select Horizontal
else select Vertical for vertical plain detection.

[image]

Comment: It does detect the plane, but the indicator dissapears due to orientation issue,thats why I posted the issue

Comment: The AR vertical detection never detects a white/same colour vertical walls easily.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
arOrigin.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.Planes);
```

with:

```
arOrigin.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.All);
```

It should be fine.